# вывод карты в php цикле

Tags: javascript, php, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

почему не выводятся карты в цикле не понятно

```
<?php $i = 0; foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem) : ?>
<?php $i++; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var ymaps = window.ymaps;

  ymaps.ready(init);

  function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("sat_map_<?=$i;?>", {
        // Центр карты, указываем коордианты
      center: [34, 54],
        // Масштаб, тут все просто
      zoom: 10,
        // Отключаем все элементы управления
      controls: []
    }); 
  }
</script>

<div class="contact-page__map">
  <div id="sat_map_<?=$i;?>" style="width: 100%; height: 240"></div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.